# User that be able to view a specific collection only

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

is that possible to create a user in MongoDB that is only able to view a specific collection with reading permission only, no other privileges are granted?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, You'll need to create a customized role. Then assign it to a new User in the DB.

**Custom Role Command**:

```
use testdb
db.createRole(

{

createRole: "readTestColOnly",

privileges: [

{ resource: { db: "testdb", collection: "testcollection" },

actions: [ "find" ] }

],

roles: []

})
```

**New User Command:**

```
use testdb
db.runCommand({ 
    "createUser" : "testuser", 
    "customData" : {

    }, 
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readTestColOnly", 
            "db" : "testdb"
        }
    ]
});
```

Hope This helps.